# Confusion of de-serializing collections in gson java

Tags: java, gson

I have a question regarding the Collections in gson de-serializing

**Result :**
Line 1 : it compiled without any error.
Line 2 : it compiled without any error. Prints  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0].
Line 2 : It throws *"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to gsonUserGuide.com.google.sites.A"*

**My question:**
I know that I can specify the type correctly as follows.

```
ArrayList<Integer> aList = gson.fromJson( 
            "[1,2,3,4]", new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>() {}.getType());
```

But my question is, if it throws java.lang.ClassCastException in Line 3 why it doesn't give an error while loading values to aList at least at Runtime? 
**Code :**

```
public class OBJConversion {

    private final static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Line 1
        ArrayList<A> aList = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4]", ArrayList.class);
        // Line 2
        System.out.println("main().aList : " + aList);
        // Line 3
        System.out.println("main().someString : " + aList.get(0).getSomeString());
    }

    class A {

        String someString = null;

        public String getSomeString() {
            return someString;
        }

        public void setSomeString(String someString) {
            this.someString = someString;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why

This is one of the [Collections Limitations](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Limitations) when using GSON:

> You can serialize collection of arbitrary objects but can **not** deserialize from it because there is no way for the user to indicate the type of the resulting object.

GSON interprets `gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4]", ArrayList.class)` as a list of primitives (it cannot tell from the `ArrayList<A>` that you want type `A` because the type information is lost at runtime). GSON has [different primitives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) than Java, and does not have an `int`, so `[1,2,3,4]` is treated as a list of Numbers which are double floating point precision, a Java `Double`. Thus, GSON effectively creates a `List<Double>`.

#### Workaround

GSON suggests [three workarounds](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types):

1. Parse it by hand, as in [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java),
2. Register a type adapter for `Collection.class`, or
3. Register a type adapter for `A` and use `fromJson(aList, Collection<A>.class)`.

Option 2, for example, would look something like this:

```
public class OBJConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                // NOTE: all Lists will be treated as List<A>
                .registerTypeAdapter(List.class, new ACollectionAdapter())
                .create();

        // Line 1
        List<A> aList = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4]", List.class));
        // Line 2
        System.out.println("main().aList : " + aList);
        // Line 3
        System.out.println("main().someString : " + aList.get(0).getSomeString());
    }

    static class ACollectionAdapter extends TypeAdapter<List<A>> {

        @Override
        public void write(
                JsonWriter out, List<A> value) throws IOException {
            out.beginArray();
            for (A a : value) {
                out.value(a.getSomeString());
            }
            out.endArray();
        }

        @Override
        public List<A> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();
            in.beginArray();
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                A a = new A();
                a.setSomeString(in.nextString());
                as.add(a);
            }
            in.endArray();
            return as;
        }
    }

    static class A {

        String someString = null;

        public String getSomeString() {
            return someString;
        }

        public void setSomeString(String someString) {
            this.someString = someString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it kuporific. Thank you for the nice explanation

Answer (score 2):

That's because the type information (the `<A>` in `ArrayList<A>`) is no longer available at run-time. Generic types are used exclusively during compilation and are "erased" afterwards, and the code is finally compiled into something like

```
ArrayList aList = gson.fromJson("[1,2,3,4]", ArrayList.class);
```

(note the removal of the `<A>` type argument in the declaration) This is the reason, why you have to provide the type information (via "type token") at run-time, if you want to make the code really type safe. The type information is only available under special circumstances (which is actually used by the type token implementation).